# Macro is running twice when launch via python

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

Challenge:
I am running Excel macro via python and macro shows date entry form. But Once I enter a date in entry form in macro and click OK button, same entry form is showing again and need to enter it.

In macro, I am calling entry form 1 time only.

```vb
Sub Load_NAV_Data()
    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strStandardDate As String
    Dim intNumberColumns As Long
    Dim intNumberRows As Long

    Dim objCol As Object
    Dim ingColSu As Long
    Dim iCols As Long

    '--------------------------------
    ' Connect to DB
    '--------------------------------

    '--------------------------------
    ' Get standard date
    '--------------------------------
    StandardDateForm.Show
    strStandardDate = StandardDateForm.StandardDate
    Unload StandardDateForm

    If strStandardDate = StrConv(strStandardDate, vbWide) Then
        strStandardDate = StrConv(strStandardDate, vbNarrow)
    End If

    MsgBox strStandardDate

    '--------------------------------
    ' SQL
    '--------------------------------
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    strSQL = "SELECT HR.ID,"
    strSQL = strSQL & "HR.EMPNAME "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM HR "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (HR.Date='" & strStandardDate & "') AND (HR.WORKINGYEAR>$0)"

    Rs.Open strSQL, cn

    '--------------------------------
    ' Get Column Name
    '--------------------------------
    For intNumberColumns = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("NAV Price").Cells(1, intNumberColumns + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(intNumberColumns).Name
    Next intNumberColumns


    '--------------------------------
    ' Output to Excel
    '--------------------------------
    intNumberRows = 2

    Do Until Rs.EOF
        Cells(intNumberRows, 1).Value = Rs.Fields("ID").Value
        Cells(intNumberRows, 2).Value = Rs.Fields("EMPNAME").Value

        intNumberRows = intNumberRows + 1
        Rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    '--------------------------------
    ' Disconnect to DB
    '--------------------------------

    If Not Rs Is Nothing Then
        If Rs.State = adStateOpen Then Rs.Close
        Set Rs = Nothing
        End If
    If Not cn Is Nothing Then
        If cn.State = adStateOpen Then cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
    End If

    cn.Close
    Rs.Close

ERR_HANDLER:
    'Error message
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ")" & Err.Description
    MsgBox Err.Number & ")" & Err.Description

    '--------------------------------
    ' Disconnect to DB
    '--------------------------------
    If Not Rs Is Nothing Then
        If Rs.State = adStateOpen Then Rs.Close
        Set Rs = Nothing
        End If
    If Not cn Is Nothing Then
        If cn.State = adStateOpen Then cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

From python, we call macro with below

```py
excel = Win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 0

private_wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("Macro file path")
data_sheet = private_wb.Worksheets("Data")
excel.Application.Run("Macro.Load_NAV_Data()")

private_wb.Close(SaveChanges = 1)

--- skip logic ---

submit_wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
submit_sheet = submit_wb.Worksheets(1)
submit_sheet.name = "Submit"

submit_wb.SaveAs("Path where to save")
private_wb.Close(SaveChanges = 0)
submit_wb.Close(SaveChanges = 0)
```

When I run macro only, entry form will show one time only but from python shows twice.

Would you please guide me to resolve the issue?

Comment: "python shows twice" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: I wanted to say that entry form will be shown twice when I launch python.

Comment: OK - understood.  I'm not a big Python user, so can't comment much on that part, except you're closing `private_wb` twice?  I don't see anything in the VBA which would cause the userform to show twice.  You have the Excel instance set to hidden though when you open it via Python, so I'm surprised you see the form at all ?

Comment: @Tim Williams, Thanks your comment, as you can see, there is no code to cause the userform twice, really wired. I will take alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same problem, this is simply due to the brackets when calling the VBA Sub. If the sub doesn't require any parameters, there is no need for brackets.

Instead of this:

```
excel.Application.Run("Macro.Load_NAV_Data()")
```

It should be:

```
excel.Application.Run("Macro.Load_NAV_Data")
```